# Should we Use sprite sheet in the era of modern browsers or not?

Tags: html, css, page-load-time

I want to know if using a single sprite sheet for whole site is still a best practice in the era of modern browser who can handle multiple HTTP request. As sprite sheet can get bigger for a big site and if page tends to use only a few of the images/icons from the sprite sheet having around 100 image and icons in them.

Answer (score 0):

The browser isn't the problem or the solution in this case. It is, as you hinted, all a matter of download time and size. These are still relevant. Mobile phones can have a slow connection, so you want to limit the amount of data, and the number of individual files, to be downloaded.

So if each page of a site only uses a few sprites from a big sheet then that sheet might not be the best choice. However, you can still use a sheet for those few sprites that are on most pages.

Perhaps it is also important to look at the content of the sheet itself. If all sprites are in the same color you can create a very small PNG file out of it. I see that many images files, used online, have not been optimized.